# react navigation "navigate" function not working inside firebase Asynchronous login function

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm following the famous tutorial of "the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course",
i'm implementing react-navigation with redux and firebase, my problem is that its using the obsolete "react-native-router-flux" approach, i tried to follow it, but the project is not building at all.

I tried to migrate it step by step the the official react-navigation, the problem is, when trying to navigate from inside Asynchronous function (like firebase login function), navigation is not working, (putting in mind that i'm using redux)

**Update: Solution found, below is working code:

here is my Asynchronous function code (inside actions.js):

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

import {
    EMAIL_CHANGED,
    PASSWORD_CHANGED,
    LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
    LOGIN_USER
} from './types';

export const emailChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
        payload: text

    };
};

export const passwordChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: PASSWORD_CHANGED,
        payload: text

    };
};

export const loginUser = ({email, password}, NavigationActions) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        //indicate start user log in process
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER});

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user, NavigationActions))
            .catch(() => {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(user  => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user, NavigationActions))
                    .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
        });
    };
};

const loginUserFail = (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL});
}

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user, NavigationActions) => {

    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user,

    });


      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'employeeList' })

    };
```

and my router file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import EmployeeList from './components/EmployeeList';


const Router = StackNavigator({
    login: { screen: LoginForm },
    employeeList: {screen: EmployeeList },

   },
   {

    initialRouteName: 'login',
   });

export default Router;
```

and App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
//import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import Router from './Router';

class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount(){
        const config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyDV_vLg656D36E8T9GVraA6ZmZrcUi2QH4",
            authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "manager-ba44d",
            storageBucket: "manager-ba44d.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "200262066369"
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }

    render() {
        const store= createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router />
            </Provider>

        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

my login component that calls the Asynch function:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../actions';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button, Spinner } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = () => ({
        title: 'Login screen',
        headerTitleStyle: { 
            textAlign:"center", 
            flex:1
         }
    });

    onEmailChange(text){
        this.props.emailChanged(text);
    }

    onPasswordChange(text){
        this.props.passwordChanged(text);
    }


    onButtonPress(){
        const {email, password, navigation} = this.props;
        this.props.loginUser({email, password}, navigation);
    }

    renderError(){
        if(this.props.error){
            return(
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                    <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>
                        {this.props.error}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }

    renderButton(){
        if(this.props.loading){
            return <Spinner size="large" />;
        }

        return (
            <Button 
                    style={styles.buttonStyle}
                    buttonText="Login" onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
            </Button>
        );

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input 
                    label="Email"
                    placeholder="email@gmail.com"
                    onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.props.email}
                    />
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <Input 
                    secureTextEntry
                    label="password"
                    placeholder="password"
                    onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.props.password}
                    />

                </CardSection>

                {this.renderError()}

                <CardSection>

                    {this.renderButton()}
                </CardSection>
            </Card>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        email: state.auth.email,
        password: state.auth.password,
        error: state.auth.error,
        loading: state.auth.loading

    };

};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, 
    { 
    emailChanged,
    passwordChanged,
    loginUser
    })(LoginForm);


    const styles = {
        errorTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 20,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            color: 'red'

        },
        buttonStyle:{
            flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignSelf: 'stretch'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You need to import NavigationActions like this

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

export const loginUser = ({email, password}, navigation) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        //indicate start user log in process
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER});

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
        .then(NavigationActions.navigate('employeeList'))
        .catch(() => {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(user  => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user, navigation))
                    .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
        });
    };
};

const loginUserFail = (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL});
}

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user, navigation) => {

    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user,

    });

   NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'employeeList' })],
    }),


};
```

Comment: I tried your code, its the same, except you made another function inside the Asynch login function, can you put full code example showing how to navigate to another screen after successful login, and if there any code need to be added in reducer file or not?

Comment: you need to pass this.props.navigation to loginUser in order to use the navigation. Can you show a more code that from where are you calling loginUser from?

Comment: please see complete code in original post, i edited it.

Comment: how are you dispatching your actions from components?

Comment: Really appreciate your help Haider, but still not working, do we need to put anything in reducer ?   *note: do we need to replace navigation with "navigationActions" maybe ?!!

Comment: Look, as you may noticed, there is an error variable in state which i handle login failure with, it looks like :                                                                        
 case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
            return { ...state, error: 'Authentication Faild!', password: '', loading: false}      i'm getting this error, but through the course, he said that this is not actually Auth. error (assuming that i'm putting correct login info for sure) but this error happens when it fails to run code after successful login, this means the navigation code didn't go correctly

Comment: Updated the answer mate, looks like you need to use NavigationActions.

Comment: Thanks bro, it works fine right now after replacing every "navigation" with "navigationActions", you was a great help to me. 1000+ thanks to you :)

Comment: can you accept and upvote the answer please, Thanks :)